# Can't mount all files to docker container volume

Tags: deployment, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-volume

I always use docker to deploy my django apps but today I got an problem.

This is `uwsgi` container in the docker-compose.yml file.

```
uwsgi:
  # Note you cannot scale if you use conteiner_name
  container_name: catalogue-uwsgi
  build: docker
  hostname: uwsgi
  environment:
    - DATABASE_NAME=gis
    - DATABASE_USERNAME=docker
    - DATABASE_PASSWORD=docker
    - DATABASE_HOST=db
    - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
    - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.prod_docker
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=catalogue.kartoza.com
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
  volumes:
    - ../django_project:/home/web/django_project
    - ./static:/home/web/static
    - ./media:/home/web/media
    - ./reports:/home/web/reports
    - ./logs:/var/log/
    - ./data:/home/web/django_project/data
  links:
    - smtp:smtp
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    - worker:worker
  restart: on-failure:5
```

Everything is working fine, but I need to mount one directory which contain so many thumbnail files. The size is pretty big.

I added this line `/EOSHARE/Karabo/CATALOGUE/thumbnails_cat3:/django_project/thumbs_out`
 to the `volumes` line. Then I re-deploy the container.

The problem is some files/directories in the local directory can't be mounted. I am not sure about this, this is my first experience that I need to mount directory that has big size.

This is my analysis:

This is the `ls` of directory:

Local directory:

```
root@testenv:/EOSHARE/Karabo/CATALOGUE/thumbnails_cat3# ls
AQA  cache  E2  L3  L5  N11  N14  N16  N9   RE2  RE4  S1  S3  S5    S-C  ZA2
C2B  E1     L2  L4  L7  N12  N15  N17  RE1  RE3  RE5  S2  S4  SACC  TER
root@testenv:/EOSHARE/Karabo/CATALOGUE/thumbnails_cat3#
```

Docker container:

```
root@uwsgi:/home/web/django_project/thumbs_out# ls
S1  S2  S4  S5  cache
```

The docker container size:

```
root@testenv:/home/web/catalogue/deployment# docker ps -s
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES                     SIZE
f1380ac2e1f1        catalogue_uwsgi           "python manage.py mig"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        8080/tcp                                   catalogue_uwsgi_run_119   283.4 kB (virtual 2.468 GB)
c18553c5141b        nginx                     "nginx -g 'daemon off"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:62080->8080/tcp   catalogue-web             2 B (virtual 190.5 MB)
0bb98b3f4500        catalogue_uwsgi           "uwsgi --ini /uwsgi.c"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        8080/tcp                                   catalogue-uwsgi           252.7 kB (virtual 2.468 GB)
b9166d6cfa8d        catalogue_worker          "celery worker -A cat"   8 days ago          Up 8 days           8080/tcp                                   catalogue_worker_1        373.2 kB (virtual 2.468 GB)
bd65f624cded        library/rabbitmq          "/docker-entrypoint.s"   8 days ago          Up 8 days           4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp         catalogue_rabbitmq_1      0 B (virtual 300.8 MB)
07f212b09ef8        kartoza/pg-backup:9.4     "/start.sh"              12 weeks ago        Up 4 weeks          5432/tcp                                   catalogue-db-backups      1.071 MB (virtual 497.9 MB)
d32576b47c75        catatnight/postfix        "/bin/sh -c '/opt/ins"   12 weeks ago        Up 4 weeks                                                     catalogue-smtp            11.42 MB (virtual 268 MB)
6404c753dbf8        kartoza/postgis:9.4-2.1   "/bin/sh -c /start-po"   12 weeks ago        Up 6 days           5432/tcp                                   catalogue-db              3.915 GB (virtual 4.411 GB)
```

Inside the container:

```
root@uwsgi:/home/web/django_project# df -h
Filesystem                                                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                                                                  73G   73G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d02bdc6c-2230-40ce-8407-079095f72488                73G   73G     0 100% /var/log
41.74.147.98:/lustre/lfs01/EOSHARE/Karabo/CATALOGUE/thumbnails_cat3  151T  134T  9.8T  94% /home/web/django_project/thumbs_out
shm                                                                   64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

I've looking the answer about the maximum size of docker container also I've trid to made a volume (docker volume) then mount the directory to that volume and the result is same. Not all directory can be mounted.

My questions are:

1. Is there any maximal size for the docker container, if yes, how much
   is it and how to increased it?
2. With this problem, is there any best approach to mount big size
   directory to the docker container?
3. The output of `docker ps -s` shows that the virtual size around GB
   but when I exec to the container then `df -h` the output in T -> see
   the output above `151T  134T`.

Thanks.

Comment: You are mounting in /django_project/thumbs_out and checking in a different directory (/home/web/django_project/thumbs_out). That is why.

Comment: did you see this one? ` - ../django_project:/home/web/django_project` That is correct path.

Comment: Inside the container, run `ls /django_project/thumbs_out`, you'll see what I mean.